# Unwrapping and replacing two positive-side battery cables

Tags: pontiac

There are two, not one, battery cables on the positive-side of my Pontiac Vibe's battery. One of the cables is considerably thicker than the other. I'm not sure what function that smaller cable has, but in any case, it's there.

After some corrosion and an emergency stop, I had to clip the two cables and used a new clamp. But it's a patch job. Now the cables are too short and the lead is sitting at a slant.

I'd like to replace the two (positive-side) cables, but they are wrapped with other cables eight or so inches after leaving the battery.

Can I safely unravel that wrapping and replace just the two (positive-side) battery cables, or do I have to replace the entire set of cables as a unit?

Answer (score 1):

Although I can't say for sure about your Vibe, many systems use two cables. One cable goes directly to the starter solenoid. The second wire powers everything else via a power distribution block. After you remove the wrapping, remove the cables and measure them for length. It may help to bring them with you to the parts supplier to match them up as far as length and connector type. Install the cables and rewrap them into the harness in the same location as before.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about the Vibe specifically, but you could always unwrap those cables and see how easily the two defective cables can be replaced.  I'm guessing you'll be able to replace just those two cables, not the whole harness.